# PHP/cURL post, just returns the page as if no post was made

Tags: php, curl

My goal is to get the prices from this site: http://nl.myprotein.com/sports-nutrition/impact-whey-protein/10530943.html.

There is a price field on the site that is edited once a user selects a certain option

Option code:

```
<form action="10530943.html" method="post" class="field">
   <fieldset>
   <legend>Hoeveelheid</legend>
   <label for="opts-7" class="">Hoeveelheid</label>
   <select name="option" id="opts-7">
      <option value="5859" selected>1 kg</option>
      <option value="5913">2.5 kg</option>
      <option value="5935">5 kg</option>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="variation" value="7"/>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the area where the price is updated once a selection box has been chosen:

```
<h2 class="price">
<span itemprop="price">&euro;15,99</span>
</h2>
```

Im using cURL to post the form to the aforementioned URL with this PHP code:

```
$URL = "http://nl.myprotein.com/sports-nutrition/impact-whey-protein/10530943.html";

$c = curl_init();
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
'option' => '5935',
'variation' => '7'
);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$contents = curl_exec($c);
$info = curl_getinfo($c);
curl_close($c);
```

The website just responds as if no post was made. The first option is selected regardless of my input. How is this possible? Obviously something is wrong here. Is it because the way they handle the post-data am I missing something here?

Comment: so is it only the price you need to get from the mentioned site?

Comment: yes i want to extract the price. default it is set to the 1kg price: 15,99 but i want to get the other prices as well (2.5kg price, 5kg price)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a request which was sent by my browser to get information about price.

```
POST /variations.json?productId=10530943 HTTP/1.1
Host: nl.myprotein.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 88
Origin: http://nl.myprotein.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
ADRUM: isAjax:true
Referer: http://nl.myprotein.com/sports-nutrition/impact-whey-protein/10530943.html

selected=3&variation1=5&option1=2408&variation2=6&option2=2407&variation3=7&option3=5913
```

I removed some browser-specific headers. If you use obtained information, you should be able to invoke POST request on your own. Form data are on the last line of the request.

JSON was returned by the server:

```
{"selected-product-id":10530986,"price":"&euro;35,99","rrp":35.99,"rrpDisplay":"&euro;35,99","rrpSaving":"&euro;0,00","rrpSavingPercent":null,"title":"Impact Whey Protein - Naturel - Zak - 2.5 kg","images":[{"index":0,"type":"thumbnail","name":"productimg/0/70/70/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"product","name":"productimg/0/130/130/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"large","name":"productimg/0/180/180/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"extralarge","name":"productimg/0/600/600/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"small","name":"productimg/0/50/50/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"extrasmall","name":"productimg/0/20/20/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"raw","name":"productimg/0/270/270/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"largeproduct","name":"productimg/0/300/300/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"zoom","name":"productimg/0/960/960/43/10530943-1395068394-710040.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"smallthumb","name":"productimg/60/60/10530943-1454294063056312.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"smallprod","name":"productimg/100/100/10530943-1454294063056312.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"list","name":"productimg/200/200/10530943-1454294063056312.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"quickview","name":"productimg/350/350/10530943-1454294063056312.jpg"},{"index":0,"type":"carousel","name":"productimg/480/480/10530943-1454294063056312.jpg"}],"bulk-buy":[],"variations":[{"id":5,"variation":"Flavour","options":[{"id":2408,"name":"Naturel","value":"Unflavoured"}]},{"id":6,"variation":"Package","options":[{"id":2407,"name":"Pouch","value":"Pouch"}]},{"id":7,"variation":"Amount","options":[{"id":5913,"name":"2.5 kg","value":"2.5"}]}]}
```

Information about price of selected product is in `price` or `rrp` variable (price is with currency mark).

Comment: Thanks alot, this is realy fantastic! i can just acces the json like this:http://nl.myprotein.com/variations.json?productId=10530943&selected=3&variation1=5&option1=2408&variation2=6&option2=2407&variation3=7&option3=5935

Comment: What program are you using to get the information about the headers?

Especially this part is very handy:
selected=3&variation1=5&option1=2408&variation2=6&option2=2407&variation3=7&option3=5913

Comment: I got it from my chromium browser. Like Alex got it below, I just copied more information from it. Just opened developer tools, switched to network tab and repeated the request.

Answer (score 4):

This site use JavaScript to get this information.

If you user debug tools from Firefox (or Chrome) you can check network activity when you change the form value.

You'll see a POST call to http://nl.myprotein.com/variations.json?productId=10530943

You've to curl on this URL with the good parameters. See screenshots below:

Headers
[image]

Post Params
[image]

Result
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that it was going to a json file but didnt knew that it was not displaying all its contents. Found out it was like php file.. Lol such a noob am I!

Comment: We all starts as noob ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and you will get the price:

```
$get_price = explode('<span itemprop="price">', $contents);
$the_price = explode('</span>', $get_price[1]);

echo $the_price[0];
```

Just put the code after `$contents = curl_exec($c);` line

The other 2 answer is fine and fetchs you json data which is a good solution, too. But this is only if you wanted to get the price as referring to your question.